# How do I filter folders based on modified date using os.walk?

Tags: python, python-datetime, os.walk, os.path

I'm iterating through a huge directory, but since it contains >500k files, I want to filter the folders that the function enters based on their last modified date.

I only want to enter folders that have been modified within the last 7 days.

This is my code so far:

```
def checkFolderFileTimestamps(rootFolder):
    
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootFolder):
            print(datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(root))).strftime("%Y:%m:%d"))
            
            for file in files:
          
                if file.endswith(".png") and datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(root, file))).strftime("%Y:%m:%d") > datetime.now().strftime("2021:5:1"):
                    print(os.path.join(root, file))
                    print(datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(root, file))).strftime("%Y:%m:%d") == datetime.now().strftime("%Y:%m:%d"))

                    imageArray.append(os.path.join(root, file))
                    imageName.append(file)
                    print(imageArray)
```

Comment: So what you want is... Search through the root folder for subfolders that were last modified upto a week ago, if so, search for files and sub-sub folders within those subfolders. Otherwise if the subfolder hasnt been modified recently, ignore those subfolders?

Answer (score 2):

Put your root folder inside `os.walk()`. You can adjust `path.endswith()` according to your requirement.

```
import os
import datetime as dt

now = dt.datetime.now()
ago = now-dt.timedelta(days=7)

modified=[]

for root, dirs,files in os.walk('C:/Users/raghavg/heads/LiveProjects/'):  
    for fname in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, fname)
        st = os.stat(path)    
        mtime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_mtime)
        if mtime > ago and path.endswith((".pdf",".png")):
            modified.append(path)
                
print(modified)
```

modified should have all the paths to the files you updated within last week

Comment: Not quite sure on how i should do this

Comment: @ChristianAabyHøgh Can you give layout of your dirs if it's not confidential. I'm not sure what you want here. Attach a screenshot in the question and update whether you want to retrieve filename which has been modified in the last 1 week or directly return the folder directory for the same. Also the level of depth your directory has

Comment: alright, windows have been counting the files and folders for 30min now... and up until now.

It has detected 250k files, and 35k folders..

So the thing is, theese folders contain a lot of files and i am only looking for the PNG files.
These files needs to be detected and uploaded to a system.

But to speed things up, i want to first search the initial root folder which contains 215 folders.. But a lot of theese folders have not been modified for years and inside theese folders you will find folders in folders in folders and so on containing files..

Comment: So to decrease the search time i just wont to sort the folders based on the last modified date. SO whenever my function enters a new folder it does not have to iterate through everything..
I hope this makes sense to you :)

So it only enters folders which have last been modified within the last 7 days

Comment: forgot to tag you @RaghavGupta

Comment: okay so if there is an image inside folder which has been modified within last week, would you rather get the folder name only or you need the image name along with that folder name.

Comment: Yea i want the image name and the path.. So that i can add the path to an array and the POST the array to the system

Comment: That is some awesome code thank you, but i does not really sort the folders they way i want them to... it still iterates through everything folder, i only want it to iterate through folders that have been modified within the last 7 days

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the assumption that you are looking to create a list of folders in the root folder that have been modified in the last 7 days.

```
import datetime
import os
# Date a week ago
week_ago = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
```

You can check if a date is less than a week ago with a simple comparison.

```
today = datetime.date.today()
print(today > week_ago)
# Output is True
```

The following code generates the list of folders in `rootFolder` that were modified in the last 7 days.

```
folders = [os.path.join(rootFolder,f.name) for f in os.scandir(rootFolder)
           if f.is_dir() and
           datetime.date.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(rootFolder,f))) > week_ago]
```

Comment: Yes but as i wrote " But to speed things up, i want to first search the initial root folder which contains 215 folders.. But a lot of theese folders have not been modified for years and inside theese folders you will find folders in folders in folders and so on containing files"

I first i need to sort the root folder, and then iterate through the latest modfied folders leaving the others out, and then repeat this process inside the next folders.

Comment: That requirement is not in the question you asked.

Comment: Did you forget `import datetime`? `datetime.date.today()` is part of the standard library. https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today

Comment: Yes i did...

"I only want to enter folders that have been modified within the last 7 days."

I dont want to iterate through every folder. i have 237.2255 files and 40.273 folders...

Comment: The code I posted creates a list of paths for folders within the provided folder that have a modified date within the last 7 days. You're free to use the same pattern within sub folders.